# Show only one result in sql LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

```
  Table A
    id | kind  | item_name
    ---+-------+----------
    1  | one   | item_1
    2  | one   | item_2

    Table B
    tableA_id | kind  | price
    ----------+-------+------
    1         | all | $10
    1         | one | $2
```

then i have a query like this

```
    SELECT a.id, a.kind, a.name, b.price FROM table_a a 
     LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.tableA_id = a.id 
     AND (a.kind = b.kind OR a.kind = 'all') 
    WHERE a.id = 1
```

Basically i want to show the price of `all` if the kind does not exist in `table b`, however if the `kind` is exist then show only the price `one` as example. but my query show both `all` and `one`.

The result of the about query is like this:

```
        id | kind  | item_name | price
        ---+-------+-----------+------
        1  | all   | item_1    | $10
        1  | one   | item_1    | $2
```

I expect this

```
        id | kind  | item_name | price
        ---+-------+-----------+------
        1  | one   | item_1    | $2
```

Comment: According to provided data set `a.kind = 'all'` this condition will never return true because there are no rows in tablea with kind = 'all'

Comment: @i-faith, how come you're expecting 2 as `id` in your result when you set `a.id=1` in your query? Is it not supposed to be 1 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

> Basically i want to show the price of all if the kind does not exist
>   in table b, however if the kind is exist then show only the price  one
>   as example.

For this, you can use `CASE` expression to do this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.kind, a.item_name,
CASE WHEN b.price IS NULL
       THEN (SELECT b2.Price
             FROM table_b AS b2 
             WHERE b2.kind = 'all')
        ELSE b.price
        END AS PRice
FROM table_a a 
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.tableA_id = a.id 
     AND b.kind = 'one' 
WHERE a.id = 1
```

[updated fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/382817/1)

Comment: *Basically i want to show the price of all if the kind does not exist in table b*  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bdd5/2 this is returning now rows your solution will  work only if there exist kind in tableb except `all`

Comment: @i-faith After your updated question, my answer will give exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid After the OP updated his question I think my answer is correct now, what do you think now?

Comment: Please have a look if there is only single row with kind all i guess it should return ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bdd5/2 what do you say about this *Basically i want to show the price of all if the kind does not exist in table b*

Comment: @HuntGeo but it does not show anything if the kind ' `one` does not exist it table b

Comment: @i-faith In this case what is the desired results? Please see my updated answer

Comment: @HuntGeo I only need 1 result. 
result show `all` if the kind `one` does not exist in `table b`, if exist then show `one` not `all`. thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @i-faith I see, try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/382817/1  it will give you price of 10 if the second row doesn't exist and will give you the price of 2 if the second row exists and in both casees only one row will be returned.

Comment: @i-faith - You're welcome, and sorry for misunderstanding in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in theory, but you're doing two joins:

```
SELECT a.id, a.kind, a.name, COALESCE(b1.price, b2.price) AS price
FROM table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b1
    ON b1.tableA_id = a.id
    AND b1.kind = a.kind
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b2
    ON b1.tableA_id = a.id
    AND b1.kind = 'all'
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

Could be more efficient. Basically you're first finding whether there is something with matching kind price and fallback to `'all'` price.

Also - if `table_b` is always going to have item price for `'all`' you could change that left join to inner join.

Answer (score 0):

To pick single row for your scenario you would need another self join in your query with additional comparison check to pick single row if another kind exist in table b else show a row with kind = `all`

```
SELECT a.id, a.kind, a.item_name, b.price
FROM table_a a 
INNER JOIN table_b b ON b.tableA_id = a.id 
LEFT JOIN table_b b1 ON b.tableA_id = b1.tableA_id 
AND b.kind < b1.kind
WHERE b1.tableA_id IS NULL;
```

[DEMO where kind exist](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7bb2a/16)

[DEMO where kind doesn't exist](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bdd5/6)

Make sure the keyword is 'all' starts with `a` then this `b.kind < b1.kind` can work properly because if you do

```
select 'all' < 'one'; // will return true
select 'all' > 'one'; // will return false
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bdd5/7)